# JS filtering two array of object. not getting the unique one

Tags: javascript

i am trying to filter the values of array one from array two. but i am not getting the three values. i only need the object with unique id.

i need { id: 28 ,name: "sdfsdf"} .. this only

i am trying this now . but getting there .any help ?

```js
var arr1 = [
        {   
         id :  { oid : 23 },
         name : "nahid"
        } , 
        
         {  
         
         id :  { oid : 24 },
         name : "nahidsdsd"
    
        } , 
         {  
         
         id :  { oid : 26 },
         name : "nahidtytuyu"
    
        } , 
       
    ]
    
    var arr2 = [
         {   
         id :  { oid : 23 },
         name : "nahid"
        } , 
        
         {  
         
         id :  { oid : 24 },
         name : "nahidsdsd"
    
        } , 
         {  
         
         id :  { oid : 26 },
         name : "nahidtytuyu"
    
        } , 
         {  
         id :  { oid : 28 },
         name : "nahidtytuyu"
         } , 
    ]
    
    
    var res = arr2.filter( data => {
    
       var temp; 
       arr1.map( data2 =>  {
           temp = data2;
       } )
       
        return temp.id.oid != data.id.oid
     
        
    } )
    
    console.log(res)
```

> (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
>   0
>   :
>   {id: {…}, name: "nahid"}
>   1
>   :
>   {id: {…}, name: "nahidsdsd"}
>   2
>   :
>   {id: {…}, name: "nahidtytuyu"}
>   length
>   :
>   3

Comment: what you need as a result? didnt get your requiremtnt

Comment: i need { id: 28 ,name: "sdfsdf"} .. this only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the required answer for you,

```js
    var arr1 = [
        {   
         id :  { oid : 23 },
         name : "nahid"
        } , 
    
         {  
    
         id :  { oid : 24 },
         name : "nahidsdsd"
    
        } , 
         {  
    
         id :  { oid : 26 },
         name : "nahidtytuyu"
    
        } , 
    
    ]
    
    var arr2 = [
         {   
         id :  { oid : 23 },
         name : "nahid"
        } , 
    
         {  
    
         id :  { oid : 24 },
         name : "nahidsdsd"
    
        } , 
         {  
    
         id :  { oid : 26 },
         name : "nahidtytuyu"
    
        } , 
         {  
         id :  { oid : 28 },
         name : "nahidtytuyu"
         } , 
    ]
    
    function difference(otherArray){
      return function(current){
        return otherArray.filter(function(other){
          return other.id.oid == current.id.oid
        }).length == 0;
      }
    }
    
    var onlyInA = arr1.filter(difference(arr2));
    var onlyInB = arr2.filter(difference(arr1));
    
    result = onlyInA.concat(onlyInB);
    console.log(result)
```

**Please run above code and check console**

[**Here is a working demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AK8MRiJqknMAblpGIUrc?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = arr2.filter( data => {
var temp; 
var flag=1;

arr1.map( data2 =>  {
    temp = data2;
   if(temp.id.oid == data.id.oid)
   {
    flag= flag +1;
   }
});

if(flag == 1)
return data;
} )
console.log(res)
https://jsfiddle.net/dintal/xn2motsf/18/#&togetherjs=DEbQo04RUM
```

Comment: But this wont work, when the arrays are reversed. So it wont fulfill all use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think I get your use case now. Please check the code below

```js
var arr1 = [
        {   
         id :  { oid : 23 },
         name : "nahid"
        } , 
        {  
         id :  { oid : 24 },
         name : "nahidsdsd"
        } , 
         {  
         id :  { oid : 26 },
         name : "nahidtytuyu"
        } , 
    ]
    var arr2 = [
         {   
         id :  { oid : 23 },
         name : "nahid"
        } ,   
         {  
         id :  { oid : 24 },
         name : "nahidsdsd"
        } , 
         {  
         id :  { oid : 26 },
         name : "nahidtytuyu"
        } , 
         {  
         id :  { oid : 28 },
         name : "nahidtytuyu"
         } , 
    ]
 var idMap = arr1.map(function(e) { return e.id.oid || null ; }) 
  var idMap2 = arr2.map(function(e) { return e.id.oid || null ; }) 
 var res = arr2.filter(function(data){
 return (idMap.indexOf(data.id.oid) == -1);   
}) ;
var res2 = arr1.filter(function(data){
 return (idMap2.indexOf(data.id.oid) == -1);   
})  
  res = res.concat(res2);
  console.log("result",res);
```

Comment: But this wont work, when the arrays are reversed. So it wont fulfill all use cases.